# How to pass two parameter to <outbound-gateway> of Spring Integration

Tags: xml, spring-integration

I have something like below configs in my xml. I have to pass two params into my select query.

```
< int-jdbc:outbound-gateway data-source="datasource"
                            update="UPDATE DUMMY SET DUMMY_VALUE='test'"
                            request-channel="findPersonRequestChannel" 
                            query="select * from Person where lower(name)=:payload[name] and id =:payload[id]"
                            reply-channel="findPersonReplyChannel"                                
                            row-mapper="personResultMapper"
                            max-rows-per-poll="100" >
< /int-jdbc:outbound-gateway >
```

While doing with above way getting exceptions like :-

```
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessagingException: At most one parameter (or expression via method-level @Payload) may be mapped to the payload or Message. Found more than one on method [public abstract java.util.List org.springframework.integration.samples.jdbc.service.PersonService.findPersonByName(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)]
```

Any idea, how to resolve this error?

With one param, its working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show your `<gateway/>` configuration and `service-interface`. This problem is upstream of the jdbc gateway.

It looks like you are trying to add two values as payloads (you can only have one payload on a message) whereas your JDBC select is using two properties on a single payload.

Your single payload needs to be a JavaBean, or Map, array etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gary. Could you please point me to any tutorial which can help me on how to make payload javabean or Map or array.. Thanks in advance.. I am new to SI.

Comment: It looks like you are exploring the jdbc-sample; instead of `List<Person> findPersonByName(String name);`, use `List<Person> findPersonByNameAndId(Person person);` and populate a `Person` object with the `personId` and `name` properties, and change your select statement to use the apropriate properties.

Comment: Yes, I have done the same and its working perfectly fine. Thanks for your hint. I'll post my reply with full code tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

```
<int-jdbc:outbound-gateway data-source="datasource"     
                           request-channel="findPersonRequestChannel" 
                           query="select * from Person where name=:name and id=:id"
                           reply-sql-parameter-source-factory="requestSource1"
                           reply-channel="findPersonReplyChannel"                                
                           row-mapper="personResultMapper"
                           max-rows-per-poll="100">
</int-jdbc:outbound-gateway>


<bean id="requestSource1" class="org.springframework.integration.jdbc.ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory">
    <property name="parameterExpressions">
        <map>
            <entry key="name" value="payload.name"/>
            <entry key="id" value="payload.personId"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I have one service interface which is accepting Person obj. Setting name and id before calling the search method.

Tell me, if anyone want to know more on the same.